# Different behavior between clang and gcc-10 when linking to static library containing global variables

Tags: c, macos, gcc, clang

I have a statically linked library, containing a global variable `barvar`. I can compile the library with no problems with either gcc-10 or clang (this is on macOS Catalina). Interestingly, the behavior differs between the two when I try to link it into a program that uses the library. Here's the code:

In `globvars.h`, `int barvar` is declared:

```
#ifndef H_GLOBVARS_H                              
#define H_GLOBVARS_H                             
  
extern int barvar;                              

#endif
```

In `globvars.c`, `int barvar` is defined:

```
#include "globvars.h" 
int barvar;
```

In `foo.c`, the function `foo` sets and prints `barvar`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "globvars.h"
void foo() 
{
    barvar = 10;      
    printf("barvar is: %d\n", barvar);
    return; 
}
```

Here's `test.c`, the program that uses the library:

```
void foo(); 
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{     
    foo();            
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and link with gcc-10, no problems:

```
gcc-10 -c foo.c -o foo.o
gcc-10 -c globvars.c -o globvars.o
gcc-10 -c test.c -o test.o
gcc-ar-10 rcs liblinktest.a foo.o globvars.o
gcc -o testlinkrun test2.o -L. -llinktest
```

When I compile and link with clang, I get an undefined symbol error at the last step:

```
cc -c foo.c -o foo.o
cc -c globvars.c -o globvars.o
cc -c test.c -o test.o
ar rcs liblinktest.a foo.o globvars.o
cc -o testlinkrun test2.o -L. -llinktest
```

with error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_barvar", referenced from:
      _foo in liblinktest.a(foo.o)
```

Any ideas? Interestingly, it appears the only step that *has* to be done with gcc-10 is compiling `globvars.c`. I can use clang and the clang linker for all other steps, and everything is fine. Is it possible that clang is optimizing away all the variables in `globvars.c`? How can I prevent this?

Comment: Did you look up the symbols that are exported? There might be a difference in automatically prefixing an underscore or not.

Comment: The commands shown use an object file as input to linking, `test2.o`, that is not the output of any prior command. Are you linking the wrong file into the program?

Comment: `int barvar;` creates a tentative definition for `barvar`, which the compiler and linker treat as a “common symbol”. It looks like the linker is not taking a common symbol from a library to satisfy an undefined reference to it. I do not know the reason for that. A workaround is to change `int barvar;` to `int barvar = 0;` to make it a regular definition.

Comment: @EricPostpischil This is exactly it; `int barvar = 0` or compiling with `-fno-common` fix it. I know from gcc-9 to gcc-10 the default behavior was changed from `-fcommon` to `-fno-common`; I might see if gcc-9 fails in a similar way to clang. I would upvote your comment if I had the rep to! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As @EricPostpischil observed in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63665653/different-behavior-between-clang-and-gcc-10-when-linking-to-static-library-conta#comment112588598_63665653), the issue is that clang defaults to treating `barvar` as a common symbol. Either changing `int barvar;` to `int barvar = 0;`, or compiling with `-fno-common`, fix the issue.

Beginning with gcc-10, gcc's default behavior is `-fno-common` instead of `-fcommon`.

Comment: Still, I wonder what the rationale is for having the linker not bring in an object module that satisfies a reference. Maybe it is to prefer a hard definition that might occur in a later module, but that means some links that could succeed (tentative/common definition in a library module and no later definition) fail.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'm curious about this myself. Do you have any suggestions for where I might find an answer? Should I make a new question for it? Long time reader of stackoverflow, first time poster, still trying to feel my way around best practices.

Comment: I think it is reasonable to ask a question asking what the rationale for this behavior is. I cannot promise the voters will agree.